# Angular ui-router hide based on roles

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, authorization

I'm using Angularjs with ui-router to navigate within my web app. I'm using Web Api as my backend. I used a tutorial from [Taiseer Joudeh](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/)  to implement authentication and authorization. now that part works great but now I want to hide menu items in the front-end based on the roles of the authenticated user. I have the following code in my state provider:

```
            $stateProvider
            .state("warehouse", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/warehouse",
                template: "<ui-view/>",
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: "Warehouse"
                }
            })
            .state("warehouse.manager", {
                url: "/pt/manager",
                templateUrl: "/App/Views/Warehouse/Pt/manager.html",
                controller: "PtManagerController",
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: "PT Beheer"
                },
                data: {
                    roles: ["Admin", "User", "Manager"]
                }
            });
```

and the user data is stored in local storage which is retrieved like this in the controller:

```
$scope.currentUser = localStorageService.get("authorizationData");
```

My menu looks as follows:

```
            <li>
            <a bs-dropdown aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="header-item-toggle">Warehouse <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <!-- PTs -->
                <li class="dropdown-header">PTs</li>
                <li>
                    <a ui-sref="warehouse.manager">PT Beheer</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

The roles for the user are accessable through $scope.currentUser.roles;
But I really have no idea how to continue from here. Is there anybody that can help me or send me in the right direction? I've read some blog posts but they are very different from my solution and I'm not that experienced with Angular so I'm having trouble translating them to my situation.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the user clicking on the link, you can use an `ng-if` statement in your HTML to compare against the current user's role.

```
<li ng-if="currentUser === 'Admin'">
  <a ui-sref="warehouse.manager">PT Beheer</a>
</li>
```

To generalize this, I've used the solution of storing the user role in a service and created a directive which checks the user role. The directive can then be used like.

```
<li user-role="administrator">
  <a ui-sref="warehouse.manager">PT Beheer</a>
</li>
```

If you want to prevent the user from accessing the page via the url, you will need to write an angular config function which checks for the `$stateChangeStart` event, checks the user role and calls `preventDefault()`.

```
angular.module('myModule').config(function($rootScope, userService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    if (userService.role is not in toState.data.roles) { // pseudo code
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that helps a lot!